# Azure pipelines - activate conda environment from a powershell script doesn't work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, conda

I have an Azure Pipeline running on a hosted agent, and one of the tasks in it is a call to powershell script:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Create and activate conda myenv'
  inputs:
  filePath: some_path.ps1

Now, some_path.ps1 looks like this:
conda env create --file "myenv.yaml"
conda activate myenv
conda env list
... (after that I pack the environment into myenv.tar.gz with 'conda pack', but it's not relevant)

The creation of myenv works (I see it in the output of 'conda env list') but the activation isn't, meaning after 'conda activate myenv', the activated environment is still base.

I tried to first update the conda version on the hosted agent with "conda update -n base -c defaults conda --yes" (since the version is very old - 4.11), but it also doesn't work: after the update command I run 'conda --version' and I still see the old version (4.11)